# The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

While executing this query, I'm getting an error as,

The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator on line 102. Could you help?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getrevenue] @date1 DATE
    ,@date2 DATE
    ,@StoreNo NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_test NVARCHAR(max)

    --SET @StoreNo='68,78,104'
    SET @sql_test = 
        'SELECT  t1.transtoreno  As StoreNO ,t3.Name AS Name,
        t1.Dealdate AS Date,t1.UKEI as UKEI,
        t2.SubTotal AS SubTotal,
        t2.SubTotalDiscount AS SubToatlDiscount,
        t1.twoeyesSubtotalDiscount As TwoeyeSubTotalDiscount,
        t2.ValueInquiries AS TotalDiscount,
        t2.NetSale AS Netsale,
        t2.TotalSale AS ToatlSale,
        t2.Cash As Cash,
        t2.GiftVochuer As GiftVochuer,
        t2.Card AS Card,
        t2.Suica as Suica,
        t2.WONPOINT AS WAONPOINT,
        t1.TaxExemption AS TAXExemption,
        t2.TaxTotal AS TaxTotal,
        t2.Returngoods As Returngoods,
        t2.Regiminus As RegiMinus,
        t2.PrintRecipt As printrecipt,
        t1.Visitorcount As VisitorCount 



From 
(select         CAST( StoreNo as nvarchar) as transtoreno ,  (DealDate )as Dealdate,
                        SUM(SalePrice) AS UKEI,
                        SUM(TansuNebikiPrice)AS twoeyesdicount,
                        SUM(SubTotalNebiki2Price)AS twoeyesSubtotalDiscount,
                        SUM(TotalSalePrice-Si1Tax-RegiMinusNo)as Netsale,
                        SUM(SpecialConsumptionTaxPrice)AS TaxExemption ,
                        Sum(RegiMinusNo)AS Receiptissue,
                        SUM(VisitorCount)As Visitorcount
                        from                  POS_TtlTran
                        Group by StoreNo,DealDate)t1


left outer join 
  (Select Date as D, StoreNo as s,
   SUM(case when SerialNo like 23 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Cash,
       SUM(case when SerialNo like 31 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Card,
       SUM(case when SerialNo like 30 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as GiftVochuer,
       SUM(case when SerialNo like 138 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Returngoods,
        SUM(case when SerialNo like 160 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as PrintRecipt,
         SUM(case when SerialNo like 304 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Suica,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 26 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as WONPOINT,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 139 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Regiminus,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 4 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as SubToTal,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 7 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as SubTotalDiscount,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 8 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as TwoeyesubTotalDiscount,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 18 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as ValueInquiries, 
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 22 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as TotalSale,
        SUM(case when SerialNo like 114 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as TaxTotal,
        SUM(case when SerialNo like 2 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as NetSale
              from POS_FinTtl
    Group By StoreNo,Date)t2

On t1.transtoreno = t2.s and t1.Dealdate=t2.D

Left outer JOIN
  (select StoreNo as No , StoreName As Name 
  from Store )t3

  On t2.s= t3.No

where (t1.transtoreno IN (' 
        + CAST(@StoreNo AS VARCHAR(100)) + ') and (t1.Dealdate between ' + CAST(@date1 AS DATE) + ' and ' + CAST(@date2 AS DATE) + ')'
END
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should convert date to varchar before concatenation. Try like this,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getrevenue] @date1 DATE
    ,@date2 DATE
    ,@StoreNo NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql_test NVARCHAR(max)

    --SET @StoreNo='68,78,104'
    SET @sql_test = 
        'SELECT  t1.transtoreno  As StoreNO ,t3.Name AS Name,
        t1.Dealdate AS Date,t1.UKEI as UKEI,
        t2.SubTotal AS SubTotal,
        t2.SubTotalDiscount AS SubToatlDiscount,
        t1.twoeyesSubtotalDiscount As TwoeyeSubTotalDiscount,
        t2.ValueInquiries AS TotalDiscount,
        t2.NetSale AS Netsale,
        t2.TotalSale AS ToatlSale,
        t2.Cash As Cash,
        t2.GiftVochuer As GiftVochuer,
        t2.Card AS Card,
        t2.Suica as Suica,
        t2.WONPOINT AS WAONPOINT,
        t1.TaxExemption AS TAXExemption,
        t2.TaxTotal AS TaxTotal,
        t2.Returngoods As Returngoods,
        t2.Regiminus As RegiMinus,
        t2.PrintRecipt As printrecipt,
        t1.Visitorcount As VisitorCount 



From 
(select         CAST( StoreNo as nvarchar) as transtoreno ,  (DealDate )as Dealdate,
                        SUM(SalePrice) AS UKEI,
                        SUM(TansuNebikiPrice)AS twoeyesdicount,
                        SUM(SubTotalNebiki2Price)AS twoeyesSubtotalDiscount,
                        SUM(TotalSalePrice-Si1Tax-RegiMinusNo)as Netsale,
                        SUM(SpecialConsumptionTaxPrice)AS TaxExemption ,
                        Sum(RegiMinusNo)AS Receiptissue,
                        SUM(VisitorCount)As Visitorcount
                        from                  POS_TtlTran
                        Group by StoreNo,DealDate)t1


left outer join 
  (Select Date as D, StoreNo as s,
   SUM(case when SerialNo like 23 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Cash,
       SUM(case when SerialNo like 31 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Card,
       SUM(case when SerialNo like 30 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as GiftVochuer,
       SUM(case when SerialNo like 138 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Returngoods,
        SUM(case when SerialNo like 160 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as PrintRecipt,
         SUM(case when SerialNo like 304 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Suica,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 26 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as WONPOINT,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 139 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as Regiminus,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 4 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as SubToTal,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 7 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as SubTotalDiscount,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 8 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as TwoeyesubTotalDiscount,
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 18 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as ValueInquiries, 
          SUM(case when SerialNo like 22 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as TotalSale,
        SUM(case when SerialNo like 114 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as TaxTotal,
        SUM(case when SerialNo like 2 then DayTotalAmt else 0 end) as NetSale
              from POS_FinTtl
    Group By StoreNo,Date)t2

On t1.transtoreno = t2.s and t1.Dealdate=t2.D

Left outer JOIN
  (select StoreNo as No , StoreName As Name 
  from Store )t3

  On t2.s= t3.No

where (t1.transtoreno IN (''' 
        + CAST(@StoreNo AS VARCHAR(100)) + ''') and (t1.Dealdate between ''' + CAST(@date1 AS VARCHAR(30)) + ''' and ''' + CAST(@date2 AS VARCHAR(30)) + ''')'

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql_test
END
```

Comment: Great help :P Appreciate it. Thanks.